# Not able to return Object property values in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object

I want to return the object property value but the dot property accessor does not work. Below is my function:

```
async abc(reviewId){
    
    let b = this.get(reviewId) 
    return b
  }
```

Below is the get function abc() calls:

```
async get(reviewId) {
    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    reviewId = ObjectId(reviewId)
  
    const r = await restaurantsCollection.findOne(
      { reviews: { $elemMatch: { _id : reviewId } } },
      {"projection" : { "reviews.$": true }}
    )
  
    return r.reviews[0]

    
  }
```

I am able to return b:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("617a07afeae615cff755fec7"),
  title: 'tkl',
  reviewer: 'sm',
  rating: 1,
  dateOfReview: '15/1/2002',
  review: ' ruh'
}
```

When I return b.rating it returns undefined:

```
async abc(reviewId){

    let b = this.get(reviewId) 
    return b.rating
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A reference of set of data you get from mongodb would be helpful but did you try JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(b)) before returning b.rating?

Comment: I get this error when I add this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1, I think I have to use findOne to get entire object and then get the rating, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I had to use await in my code as the promise was waiting and so b.ratings was undefined.

```
async abc(reviewId){

    let b = await this.get(reviewId) 
    return b.rating
  }
```